# Python Tika cannot parse pdf from url

Tags: python, apache-tika, tika-server

python for parsing the online pdf for future usage. My code are below.

```
from tika import parser
import requests
import io
url = 'https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/NSS-Final-12-18-2017-0905.pdf'
response = requests.get(url)
with io.BytesIO(response.content) as open_pdf_file:
    pdfFile = parser.from_file(open_pdf_file)
print(pdfFile)
```

However, it shows

> AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'decode'

I have taken an example from [How can i read a PDF file from inline raw_bytes (not from file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177060/how-can-i-read-a-pdf-file-from-inline-raw-bytes-not-from-file)

In the example, it is using PyPDF2. But I need to use Tika as Tika has a better result than PyPDF2.

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use tika you will [need to have JAVA 8 installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514246/use-tika-with-python-runtimeerror-unable-to-start-tika-server). The code that you'll need to retrieve and print contents of a pdf is as follows:

```
from tika import parser

url = 'https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/NSS-Final-12-18-2017-0905.pdf'

pdfFile = parser.from_file(url)

print(pdfFile["content"])
```