# How to extract a column of data from an online PDF page?

Tags: python

I am interested in extracting the 'Company Name' column from this link: 
https://calgaryeconomicdevelopment.com/assets/PDFs/Industry-Quick-Lists/Energy-2019-07.pdf

I was able to achieve something similar with this solution: [How do I decode text from a pdf online with Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171154/how-do-i-decode-text-from-a-pdf-online-with-requests)

However I was wondering how would I go about extracting only the company name column from that? Since the solution returns all of the text in an unstructured format. Thanks in advance as I am fairly new to python and having difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error as the Server is preventing bots from web scraping or something. I don't quite understand it either but I found a fix which is to download the file locally first and then use tabula to get the data like so

```
import requests
from tabula import read_pdf


url = "https://calgaryeconomicdevelopment.com/assets/PDFs/Industry-Quick-Lists/Energy-2019-07.pdf"
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('data.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)

tables = read_pdf("data.pdf", pages = "all", multiple_tables = True)
```

you may then get the following message

```
tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`
```

to fix it follow the steps from this thread.
[`java` command is not found from this Python process. Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817211/java-command-is-not-found-from-this-python-process-please-ensure-java-is-inst)
and everything should be working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python library named tabula-py
You can install it using "pip install tabula-py"
You can use it as follows:

```
import tabula

file = "https://calgaryeconomicdevelopment.com/assets/PDFs/Industry-Quick-Lists/Energy-2019-07.pdf"

tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = "all", multiple_tables = True)
```

You can use this to convert the table to a csv file

```
 tabula.convert_into(file, "table.csv")
```

Then you can use csv library to get the required columns you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the code and got this error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
---
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden